# SQLite table not being created and onUpgrade is not being called

Tags: android-sqlite

> I am trying to create a database with SQLite. but I don't understand what mistake exactly I am doing in my code.. the table is not created and onUpgrade is not being called...I tried everything .. now can anyone help me out with this please?

**Java**

```java
    package com.example.mysqlitedemo;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class NewDatabsehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private  static  final String DATABASE_NAME="Profile.dB";
    private  static  final String TABLE_NAME="Profile";
    private  static  final String NAME="Nme";
    private  static  final String AGE="Age";
    private  static  final String  ID="id";
    private  static  final String PHONE="Phone";
    private  static  final String  CREATE_TABLE=
            "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255)," +
            ""+AGE+" INTEGERE," +
            ""+ID+"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+PHONE+" INTEGER);";

    private final Context context;



    public NewDatabsehelper( Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 6);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Oncreate is called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }catch ( Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Onupgrade is called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

> ***this is my mainactivity***

```java
    package com.example.mysqlitedemo;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    NewDatabsehelper newDatabsehelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        newDatabsehelper=new NewDatabsehelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=newDatabsehelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
  }
```

And after running this I found no table created in SQLite Db.

Comment: So, have you tried to upgrade your database version?

Comment: @MahmoudMohamedRamadan yes brother I kept on changing from 2 -6

Comment: @MahmoudMohamedRamadan  but i cant create the mehtod   public void OpenDatabase(){ } just like you did.. and cant access it from Mainactivity . it is marked red saying expression needed

Comment: HOW ?! I have tried that solution before and works correctly for me

Answer (score 0):

> And after running this I found no table created in SQLite Db.

I believe that **your code works**, but that **how you are trying to determine if the table exists is the issue**.

Perhaps consider the following adaptation of your code.

The adaptation makes 3 changes to allow you to see what is going on. It

1. writes messages to the log in addition to using toasts.

   1. *toasts are short-lived and can easily be missed, the log exists for much longer*
2. enables the database version to be passed to the helper.
3. in the main activity it extracts the tables from the databases's schema (aka sqlite_master) and dumps the extract data to the log.

   1. i.e. sqlite_master is queried and the returned cursor is dumped (writeen to the log).
4. after getting the first instance of NewDatabasehelper and dumping the schema, it closes that database and then gets a second instance with a higher version and again dumps the schema.

**As such it shows that the Profile table exists.**

So the modified (but functionally the same) **NewDatabsehelper** is :-

```
public class NewDatabsehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private  static  final String DATABASE_NAME="Profile.dB";
    private  static  final String TABLE_NAME="Profile";
    private  static  final String NAME="Nme";
    private  static  final String AGE="Age";
    private  static  final String  ID="id";
    private  static  final String PHONE="Phone";
    private  static  final String  CREATE_TABLE=
            "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255)," +
                    ""+AGE+" INTEGERE," +
                    ""+ID+"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+PHONE+" INTEGER);";

    private final Context context;
    private final String TAG = "DBINFO"; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED (just to tag logged messages)


    public NewDatabsehelper( Context context, int dbversion) { //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED to require passed version rather than hard coded
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, dbversion); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED to pass the  pased version to the super call
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Oncreate is called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //<<<<<<<<<< moved to outside the try/catch
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate Invoked DBVersion is " + db.getVersion()); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }catch ( Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,"onCreate Exception " + e.getMessage()); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"onUpgrade is called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //<<<<<<<<<< moved to outside the try/catch
        Log.d(TAG,"onUpgrade Invoked for version(fromDB) " + db.getVersion() + " oldVersion is " + oldVersion + " newVersion is " + newVersion);  //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        try {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"onUpgrade Exception " + e.getMessage());  //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivty** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    NewDatabsehelper newDatabsehelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
        newDatabsehelper=new NewDatabsehelper(this,10); // Changed to pass version
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=newDatabsehelper.getWritableDatabase();
        /* Added to write database schema to the log and then close the database */
        Cursor csr = sqLiteDatabase.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        
        
         /* ADDED to repeat the above BUT with higher version number, thus forcing onUpgrade */
        newDatabsehelper = new NewDatabsehelper(this,11);
        sqLiteDatabase=newDatabsehelper.getWritableDatabase();
        csr = sqLiteDatabase.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

When run and the App is new then the log includes :-

```
2021-09-23 06:28:23.871 D/DBINFO: onCreate Invoked DBVersion is 0
2021-09-23 06:28:23.872 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@b0309ff
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out: 0 {
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    type=table
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out: }
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out: 1 {
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    type=table
2021-09-23 06:28:23.873 I/System.out:    name=Profile
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    tbl_name=Profile
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE Profile ( Nme VARCHAR(255),Age INTEGERE,id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Phone INTEGER)
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out: }
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out: 2 {
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    type=table
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_sequence
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    tbl_name=sqlite_sequence
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out: }
2021-09-23 06:28:23.874 I/System.out: <<<<<




2021-09-23 06:28:23.889 D/DBINFO: onUpgrade Invoked for version(fromDB) 10 oldVersion is 10 newVersion is 11
2021-09-23 06:28:23.893 D/DBINFO: onCreate Invoked DBVersion is 10
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@d047d2a
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out: 0 {
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    type=table
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out: }
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out: 1 {
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    type=table
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_sequence
2021-09-23 06:28:23.898 I/System.out:    tbl_name=sqlite_sequence
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out: }
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out: 2 {
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    type=table
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    name=Profile
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    tbl_name=Profile
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE Profile ( Nme VARCHAR(255),Age INTEGERE,id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Phone INTEGER)
2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out: }

2021-09-23 06:28:23.899 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

So as no database exists and there is no file from which to get the version number the version number is 0 when onCreate is called (as would be expected when the App is first installed). After onCreate has been called/run then the  Profile table exists according to the schema.

- android_metadata is created by the android API and stores the locale
- sqlite_sequence is created by SQLite because you have coded AUTOINCREMENT, it is used to store the highest used rowid (your id column is an alias of the rowid column).

The second retrieval of an instance (4 blanks lines added to distinguish the second from the first) shows that

- the version of the database is 10
- onUpgrade was called and that the new version will be 11.
- onCreate was called from onUpgrade
- and again that the table exists after having been dropped.

Another way of checking if the database and tables therein exist is by using Android Stuido's App Inspector e.g. :-

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Almost everything is well BUT let me guess the issue, you can try the next code

```java
package com.example.mysqlitedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewDatabsehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Profile.dB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Profile";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String AGE = "Age";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String PHONE = "Phone";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," +
            AGE + " INTEGERE," +
            PHONE + " INTEGER," +
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);";

    private final Context context;

    public NewDatabsehelper( Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onCreate is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch ( Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onUpgrade is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

and in your `MainActivity.java`

```java
package com.example.mysqlitedemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    NewDatabsehelper newDatabsehelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        newDatabsehelper = new NewDatabsehelper(this);
        newDatabsehelper.openDatabase();
    }
}
```